Passing variables to another pipeline
I created pipeline pipeline.yaml called SourcePipeline in Azure DevOps.
Narrowed down to the essential part:
stages:
  - stage: Pre-task
    displayName: 'Pre-task execution'
    jobs:
      - job: PrepJobs
        displayName: 'Prepob'
        steps:   
          - script: |
              echo "$(Build.Repository.Uri)"
              echo "$(Build.SourceBranchName)"
              echo "$(Build.TriggeredBy.BuildId)"

In Azure DevOps I got some output to which I have questions:

For $(Build.Repository.Uri) I got vstfs:///Build/Build/759101. Why didn't I get the full url like https://dev.azure.com//?
For $(Build.SourceBranch) I got the test name like a name of my branch. Make sense, no question.
For $(Build.TriggeredBy.BuildId) I got "/home/vsts/work/_temp/4y828575020.sh: line 6: Build.TriggeredBy.BuildNumber: command not found" Why? How to reveal it?

I also created the second pipeline 2pipeline.yaml called DependantPipeline in Azure DevOps.
Narrowed down to the essential part:
trigger: none

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: SourcePipeline
    source: 'SourcePipeline '
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
          - dev/test

variables:
- name: BUILD_URI
  value: $(Build.BuildUri)
- name: PROJECT_ID
  value: $(System.TeamProjectId)
- name: TRIGGEREDBY
  value: $(Build.TriggeredBy.BuildId)
- name: BRANCH_NAME
  value: $(Build.SourceBranchName)

steps:
  - script: |
      echo "$(Build.BuildUri)"
      echo "$(Build.SourceBranchName)"
      echo "$(Build.TriggeredBy.BuildId)"

My goal is to show at least those variables which I pasted above based on the official documentation at the DependantPipeline in Azure DevOps. In this way I would know which pipeline triggered the DependantPipeline, plus several other useful information. However,
I am not able even shown that output from those variables in the origin pipeline, SourcePipeline. Nevertheless I want to see them in DependantPipeline pipeline. For example I would like to be able to click at that link which will be generated based on the $(Build.BuildUri) variable and go to the SourcePipeline directly.
EDIT 1.
Based on the first reply, it works partially, since when I specify these variables:
    steps:
      - script: |
          echo "$(resources.pipeline.SourcePipeline.projectName)"
          echo "$(resources.pipeline.SourcePipeline.pipelineName)"
          echo "$(resources.pipeline.SourcePipeline.runName)"
          echo "$(resources.pipeline.SourcePipeline.runURI)"

I got such output:
/home/vsts/work/_temp/6464gff-487fh-6542-ae66-dafgg6434.sh: line 1: resources.pipeline.SourcePipeline.projectName: command not found
SourcePipeline
8057384.5
vstfs:///Build/Build/739475


The resources.pipeline.mySourcePipeline.projectName variable does not work as expected, how to specify project name? Simply add ProjectName keyword and define the same of the project?

2/3. Works as expected.

Still, this is not valid URL which I need. It should be clickable link. For example when I use "$(Build.Repository.Uri)" in different place I got the full repository URL like a https://


From Pipeline resource metadata as predefined variables:
In each run, the metadata for a pipeline resource is available to all jobs as the following predefined variables. These variables are available to your pipeline at runtime.
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.projectName
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.projectID
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.pipelineName
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.pipelineID
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.runName
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.runID
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.runURI
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.sourceBranch
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.sourceCommit
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.sourceProvider
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.requestedFor
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.requestedForID

Where <Alias> is the the ID of the pipeline resource.
Note:

projectName is not present in the variables if the pipeline resource does not have a project value specified. The project property is optional for pipeline resources that reference a pipeline in the same project, but may be specified if desired.

Example:
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: SourcePipeline
    source: SourcePipeline
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
          - dev/test

steps:
  - script: |
      echo "$(resources.pipeline.SourcePipeline.projectName)"
      echo "$(resources.pipeline.SourcePipeline.projectID)"
      echo "$(resources.pipeline.SourcePipeline.pipelineName)"
      echo "$(resources.pipeline.SourcePipeline.pipelineID)"
      echo "$(resources.pipeline.SourcePipeline.runName)"
      echo "$(resources.pipeline.SourcePipeline.runID)"
      echo "$(resources.pipeline.SourcePipeline.runURI)"
      echo "$(resources.pipeline.SourcePipeline.sourceBranch)"
      echo "$(resources.pipeline.SourcePipeline.sourceCommit)"
      echo "$(resources.pipeline.SourcePipeline.sourceProvider)"
      echo "$(resources.pipeline.SourcePipeline.requestedFor)"
      echo "$(resources.pipeline.SourcePipeline.requestedForID)"
    displayName: Display pipeline variables

EDIT 1
A link to the triggered pipeline(s) is available in the Associated pipelines section:

Source pipeline link is available in the triggered pipeline as well:

URL to the source build is not available in the predefined variables mentioned above, but we can use the runId and the projectName (or projectId) to generate it.
Organization must be hard-coded though, as there is no predefined variable with that information:
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: SourcePipeline
    project: myproject
    source: source
    trigger: true

# Disable CI-CD trigger
trigger: none

variables:
  # use project name when the project name is specified in the pipeline resource
  - name: buildUrlUsingProjectName
    value: "$(System.CollectionUri)$(resources.pipeline.SourcePipeline.projectName)/_build/results?buildId=$(resources.pipeline.SourcePipeline.runID)"

    # use projectID when the project name is NOT specified in the pipeline resource
  - name: buildUrlUsingProjectId
    value: "$(System.CollectionUri)$(resources.pipeline.SourcePipeline.projectID)/_build/results?buildId=$(resources.pipeline.SourcePipeline.runID)"

steps:
  - checkout: none

  - script: |
      echo "projectName: $(resources.pipeline.SourcePipeline.projectName)"
      echo "projectID: $(resources.pipeline.SourcePipeline.projectID)"
      echo "runID: $(resources.pipeline.SourcePipeline.runID)"

      echo "Source pipeline URL - using project name: $(buildUrlUsingProjectName)"
      echo "Source pipeline URL - using project Id:   $(buildUrlUsingProjectId)"
    displayName: Display pipeline variables

Running the pipeline:
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/f212804d-3997-4e1e-a608-626ff1ceaf6d.sh
projectName: myproject
projectID: 606ytg10-5665-4c6a-b85a-45cab2xy8854
runID: 667
Source pipeline URL - using project name: https://xxxxxxxx.visualstudio.com/myproject/_build/results?buildId=667
Source pipeline URL - using project Id:   https://xxxxxxxx.visualstudio.com/606ytg10-5665-4c6a-b85a-45cab2xy8854/_build/results?buildId=667


Thank you Rui, I edited my questions, still it does not work as expected for each variables. Please take a look.

@Kreg have you read my note regarding projectName?

Yes, however could you give the example how to retrieve projectName? Anyway it is not so important for that goal how so to achieve the full https:// address of the source pipeline in the second one. Did you see my origin question where I asked for the URL?

@Kreg please read the note again: projectName is not present in the variables if the pipeline resource does not have a project value specified - this means you need to specify the project name when defining the pipeline resource, such as source: MyProject/SourcePipeline

Thank you, that's what I asked. Do you have idea how to pass the valid URL of the source pipeline to the second one?

@Kreg I've listed all the pipeline variables available in my answer. But if I remember correctly, somewhere in the build there is a link to the associated pipeline (i.e. the source pipeline)

I reviewed each job steps, especially those which are added always like initialize job or checkout ... and do not see url of source pipeline nowhere. Anyway still that parameter does not show the full url as expected, $(resources.pipeline.SourcePipeline.runURI).

@Kreg added more details

It really works, I see and can click at the SourcePipeline link inside of the DependantPipeline. Thank you very much @Rui.

you can remove at your code snippet at the bottom resources: (last line). Also, I see when I have the keyword added checkout: none than it fails at Terraform Init in the DependantPipeline, do you know why? When I remove it than it works perfect both with SourcePipeline.

@Kreg my pipeline is just an example - you obviously need to adapt it to your use case.

@Kreg yes in most of the cases (including managing Terraform resources) you need to checkout the code in the current repository. By default the code is checked out in a regular job if no checkout task is specified (but not in a job of type deployment)
